# Elasticsearch Index not Created

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an issue here, I installed the plugin "richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb".
To work with this,

1. I created an entry in mongodb
2. Then i created a index with river.
3. Usually now an index must be created with the elasticsearch.

But its not creating any index other than river, and nothing is shown in console rather than elasticsearch is started.

Can someone shed some light to find a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you configured mongo with replica set , you need to do it in order to get it working

Comment: @AkashYadav:Ya its configured

Comment: what do you see in localhost:9200/_plugin/river-mongodb ??